# Find (x,y) or (top,left) location of a text box or button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery in my php web page. I want to find the location of a textbox or button in a page. Please give me a sample jquery to find this. Please provide with any suggestions u have. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is way to do this in javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [jQuery Offset](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/offset). It get the current offset of the matched element, in pixels, relative to the document.

```
var textbox = jQuery("#element");
var offset = textbox.offset();
console.log("left: " + offset.left + ", top: " + offset.top );
```

See also: [selector/text](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/text) and [selector/button](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/button)

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/index.html). It also add a global variable named "console" to all web pages loaded in Firefox. In this case "console.log" writes a message to the console.

Answer (score 1):

See *positioning* into [jQuery API CSS](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS) page